# Styling classless content elements using SASS 7-1 architecture

Tags: html, css, sass

Following the architecture shown here: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/user-interfaces/building-layouts-preprocessors/7-1-sass-architecture

Where would one style `.content p`, `.content ul`, etc.?

If I use:

```
.content {
}
.content p {
}
.content ul {
}
.content__title {
}
```

Where would this go? It doesn't fit the rules of base, layout, pages, etc.

Comment: Depends on how you would like to use this class? A generic class to use on an HTML element which will be used across the site/application? If so, it goes here into the "themes", if it's specific, like a footer style, then it goes into the layout. If it's a dropdown content class, then components etc...

Comment: @PatrikAlexits it would be specific to content. <main class="content"><article><p>This needs to be styled</p></article></main>. It would also need to be available to <aside class="content">...</aside>.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating `p`, `ul`, etc. as their own components. Here is a discussion on the topic: https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/ama/issues/110